# Android app production release still has 'Early Access' suffix visible to beta users

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

In my, only first, android app release, I followed the recommended iteration method of releasing on beta test tracks to gather feedback before going full production release.

I increase build number on each releases going to beta test. Until I considered I gathered enough feedback and fix enough issues, I decided to promote my app to production track. What I did was simply click on the 'Promote Release' and 'To Production' on my last beta build. I filled in the form, and waited until review completed. The review did completed and my app went full production on Google Play

However, my beta users, those joined during beta release reported that, after the app went full production, **they still see that 'Early Access' suffix on the app title in Google Play page**.  Other people not in the beta track see regular app page. I my self see the regular app page in Google Play.

The problem here is that when my beta user leave comments and ratings after I went full production, the comments and ratings still stays in the beta test track. It does not count towards the rating of the production version. Comments aren't visible besides to other beta testers. And there are hundreds of them, I'm loosing precious comments and ratings.

I looked around the settings on Google Play Console but there seemed nothing I can do.

Should I increase build number before actually promoting to production?

Isn't this defeats the purpose of having the very same app build under test, pass test, and going to production?

Am I missing something I should do on Google Play Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your beta testers to see the production version of the app they would need to leave the beta test track.

In order to do this, they would need to visit this link: https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your.package.name/leave and press the leave beta test button. (replace "your.package.name" with your apps's package name).

Alternatively, if you are running an open beta, the users will see a leave beta program button on the Google Play store listing.

Comment: Yup, this is what I finally recommend my users to do. This is something that I need to remember next time I decide to beta test my app.